# Reclassifying multiple rasters using ModelBuilder or ArcPy using ArcMap10.1 or 10.2

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcmap, modelbuilder, reclassify

I have a folder with more than 500 raster (DEM) and I want to reclassify (equal interval method) each of them but number of classes in each case is determined by the number of 100m elevation bands. i.e number of classes =(max elevation- minimum elevation)/100. I have obtained max and minimum elevation of each raster from GetRasterProerties tool.

How do I put this custom number of classes for each raster?
[image: Model I created is attached as an image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please do not delete questions that have been closed, and then re-ask them.  Once you have edited the original question it needs to be reviewed to determine if the question is ready to be re-opened.